# Hibernate setParameter adds single quote to string

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, error-handling, prepared-statement

I'm trying to create new table using hibernate prepared statement. It looks like `"setparameter("values", value)"` adds additional quotes to query.
My code:

```
String hql = "create table :values " + "(name VARCHAR(50))";
        Query my = session.createSQLQuery(hql);
        my.setParameter("values", value);
        my.executeUpdate();
        session.close();
```

Error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [contextServlet] in context with path [/SpringSafeHouseService2.0] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''merkurijuss' (name VARCHAR(50))' at line 1
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can't use table Name as Parameter in prepared Statement. You have to put it into  the sting:

```
    String hql = "create table "+ value+ " (name VARCHAR(50))";
    Query my = session.createSQLQuery(hql);
    my.executeUpdate();
    session.close();
```

Comment: So how to prevent this query from SQL injection ?

Comment: @☺Liver SQL injection only works for values of columns not table names

Comment: So this query is completely safe from SQL injections ?
String hql = "create table "+ value+ " (name VARCHAR(50))";